# CSS проблема с отображением высоты блока на телефоне

Tags: css, wordpress

Отображения на большом екране:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В мобильной версии блок меньший, так как текста мала.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать блоки одинаковые по высоте в мобильной версии. Использую шаблон Enigma.
Слайдер Our Portfolio
http://demo.weblizar.com/preview/#enigma 
Я так понимаю нужно изменить класс enigma_home_portfolio_caption.

Answer (score 0):

Да. Задать максимальную высоту по вкусу. И равную ей высоту.

```
.enigma_home_portfolio_caption {
  max-height: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Только теперь текст не весь видно.Возможно как то, уменьшать текст если это телефон ?

Comment: Поиграйте значением. Я 150px для примера написал.

Answer (score -1):

Можно задать минимальную высоту тоже должно работать.

```
.enigma_home_portfolio_caption {
 min-height:150px;
}
```